# Lighting does not work with gluSphere

Tags: opengl, graphics, jogl

This is a simple issue that I'm somewhat ashamed to ask for help on.

I'm making a simple call to gluSphere to render a sphere, however, it does not light properly even though I'm pretty sure I added the normals and lighting correctly. If, however, I add a texture, the model lights normally, except it seems to be always SMOOTH, and I cannot change it to flat.

This is the lighting code in my init() function:

```
gl.glLightfv( GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_AMBIENT , AMBIENT_LIGHT, 0 );
gl.glLightfv( GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_DIFFUSE , DIFFUSE_LIGHT, 0 );
gl.glLightfv( GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_POSITION, light_pos    , 0 );
gl.glEnable ( GL.GL_LIGHT0 );
gl.glEnable ( GL.GL_LIGHTING );
```

this is my sphere code in my display() function:

```
gl.glColor3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glu.gluQuadricDrawStyle  (quad, GLU.GLU_FILL);
glu.gluQuadricNormals    (quad, GLU.GLU_FLAT);
glu.gluQuadricOrientation(quad, GLU.GLU_OUTSIDE);

glu.gluSphere(quad, 1.0, lat, lon);
```

Please advise.

EDIT:
light values:

```
public final static float[] DIFFUSE_LIGHT  = {  1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f };
public final static float[] AMBIENT_LIGHT  = {  0.3f, 0.3f,  0.3f, 1.0f };
public              float[] light_pos      = { -2.0f, 2.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f };
```

added materials, no change:

```
gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_AMBIENT , new float[]{0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f}, 0);
gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_DIFFUSE , new float[]{1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, 0);
gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_SPECULAR, new float[]{0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f}, 0);
gl.glMaterialf (GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_SHININESS, 0.5f);
gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_EMISSION, new float[]{0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.0f}, 0);
```

EDIT2:

Blah, I figured i had a:

```
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

active somewhere and it was causing my model not to have shading if there was no texture associated with it. -_- carry on good people, carry on.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered lighting problem too and figured out that i need to add `glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE)`.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of lighting are you expecting?  The third parameter to glLightfv is supposed to be the values of the light you are setting.

Comment: At this point, any old lighting, all I get is a black ball.

the lighting values are as follows, however, I'm not sure if it will help. They work perfectly well for any shape I manually construct with my own normals. Maybe I need to just implement my own sphere code.

added to post since comment does not auto format.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your function call.  What's your 4th parameter you are passing?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are there any translations/rotations you do that may affect the position of the light?
2. Is GL_COLOR_MATERIAL enabled or disabled? It may overwrite your material settings if it is.
3. Even if your code is not enabling GL_TEXTURE_2D, you should try disabling it manually right before the line is reached, just in case.
4. If you wish to ignore gluSphere completely, there's some code in [this thread](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=447139) that you can use.