# glutSolidSphere lighting issue when further away

Tags: glut, freeglut, glu

For some reason I get weird patchy lighting effects/flickering when using glutSolidSphere and the camera is relatively far away from the object. See below:

[image]

This also happens with glutSolidCube and I assume the others as well.

I've tried everything I could find in similar questions but no luck with that

- [Glusphere giving strange lighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046879/glusphere-giving-strange-lighting)
- [Lighting does not work with gluSphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647440/lighting-does-not-work-with-glusphere)

I've tried enabling all of the below and different combinations of the below and tried doing so in multiple places

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
```

And also removed all  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); anyhere

The problem happens when I turn on lighting with `glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);` and occurs with glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH) and glShadeModel(GL_FLAT) and also if I don't enable GL_COLOR_MATERIAL and even occurs with just a positional light like so:

```
float light_position[] = {100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f, 1.0f};
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
```

What else could this be?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the problem after forever. Apparently using a very low value (even if above zero) for zNear in the gluPerspective view causes this problem.

The following fixed the problem:

```
gluPerspective(90, (float) width / (float) height, 0.1f, Z_RANGE);
```

See: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/55516